# How to display data related to the same row in CoreData at IntentConfiguration Widget view iOS 14?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm currently developing an application using `SwiftUI` and trying to make a `widget ios 14` user can choose a data to check its detail using `IntentConfiguration`

**An outline I want to do in this App is like below:**

1. A user adds some data at an adding view (id: `UUID`, task: `String`, status: `String`, and some...) to
   `CoreData` in Host App
2. The user chooses data the user wants to check its detail in the edit widget
3. The user can check a brief detail in the widget view
4. If the user taps the widget view, can check detailed data in a detailed view in the host App

---

In my codes, I could implement almost all the functions I explain above.

But I don't know How can I display task data in the edit widget...

So far, I specify UUID data in `CoreData` as a Parameter in Configuration. Because `WidgetEntryView` needs `UUID`(or something unique value) to filter which `row` requests to `CoreData` and to make `URL` for `DeepLink` to detail view in host App.

So the list view in the widget displays UUID data like below.
[image]

But I want to display task data instead of UUID in that list view keeping to give UUID data to the Widget view as well.

If I specify task data in `CoreData` as a Parameter in Configuration, the widget displays tasks as a list. But in that case a filter for request data to `Coredata` (`NSPredicate(format: "id == %@"`) and `widgetURL()` don't work...

How could I implement this?

---

Here are the codes:

TimerIntentWidget.swift

```
import Foundation
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    typealias Intent = ConfigurationIntent
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    init(context : NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = context
    }
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        
        var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
       
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        return SimpleEntry(configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity!)
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
      
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        let entry = SimpleEntry(configuration: configuration, date: Date(), timerEntity: timerEntity!)
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        
        var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
        
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", UUID(uuidString: configuration.UUID!)! as CVarArg)
        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(configuration: configuration, date: entryDate, timerEntity: timerEntity!)
            entries.append(entry)
        }
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let date: Date
    let timerEntity:TimerEntity?

}

struct TimerIntentWidgetEntryView : View{
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(entry.timerEntity!.id!.uuidString)
            Divider()
            Text(entry.timerEntity!.task!)
            Divider()
            Text(entry.timerEntity!.status!)
            Divider()
            Text(entry.date, style: .time)
        }
        .widgetURL(makeURLScheme(id: entry.timerEntity!.id!))
    }
}

@main
struct TimerIntentWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "TimerIntentWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider(context: PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)) { entry in
            TimerIntentWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

func makeURLScheme(id: UUID) -> URL? {
    guard let url = URL(string: "timerlist://detail") else {
        return nil
    }
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
    urlComponents?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: id.uuidString)]
    return urlComponents?.url
}
```

IntentHandler.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension,ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    func provideUUIDOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")
                var nameIdentifiers:[NSString] = []
        
                do{
                    let results = try moc.fetch(request)
        
                    for result in results{
                        nameIdentifiers.append(NSString(string: result.id?.uuidString ?? ""))
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError{
                    print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
                }
        
                let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
                completion(allNameIdentifiers,nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        return self
    }
}
```

TimerIntentWidget.intentdefinition
[image]

Persistence.swift (Host App)

```
import CoreData

class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    private init() {}

    private let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let storeURL = FileManager.appGroupContainerURL.appendingPathComponent("TimerEntity")

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ListTimer")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}

extension PersistenceController {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
}

extension PersistenceController {
    var workingContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.parent = managedObjectContext
        
        return context
    }
}

import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    static let appGroupContainerURL = FileManager.default
        .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.sample.ListTimer")!
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom type for your configuration parameter. Currently you're using `String` which limits you to one value only.

Instead create a custom type, let's call it `Item`:

[image]

Now you have the `identifier` and `displayString` properties for your `Item` which can be mapped to the `UUID` and `task` properties of your model.

Then, in the `IntentHandler` instead of `INObjectCollection<NSString>?` you need to provide `INObjectCollection<Item>?` in the completion.

Assuming you already have your `results` fetched from Core Data, you only need to map them to the `Item` objects:

```
let results = try moc.fetch(request)
let items = results.map {
    Item(identifier: $0.id.uuidString, display: $0.task)
}
completion(items, nil)
```

This way you can use the `display` property to show *readable* information to the user but also have the `identifier` property which can be later used to retrieve the Core Data model.